# How to make all methods of another type methods of my defined `cdef class` in `__cinit__`/`__init__` using Cython?

Tags: python, c, cython, metaprogramming

## Objective

Let say I defined a `cdef class MyClass`, and in its `__cinit__`/`__init__` c-initializer method, I want to pass a python object (let's call it `x`), `x` becomes an attribute of `MyClass` instance (let's call it `MyClass.inner`), and make the instance of `MyClass` to have all methods of `type(x)`. I want to make all methods of `MyClass` such that the following happens:

1. When we call `MyClass().method`, it delegates the function call to `type(x).method` with the `self` parameter of `type(x).method` to `MyClass().inner`.
2. Whichever value `type(x).method` returns, it is wrapped into a new instance of `MyClass`.

e.g.

```
myclass = MyClass("hello")
mynewclass = myclass.startswith("h")
assert mynewclass == MyClass(True)
```

## Question

How do I go about doing that?

## My Solution?

This is the reference to the definition of [`PyTypeObject`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/c-api/typeobj.html?highlight=pytypeobject), there is a slot named `tp_methods` which is an array of `PyMethodDef`.

The C definition of `PyMethodDef` is copied below:

```
struct PyMethodDef {
    const char  *ml_name;   /* The name of the built-in function/method */
    PyCFunction ml_meth;    /* The C function that implements it */
    int         ml_flags;   /* Combination of METH_xxx flags, which mostly
                               describe the args expected by the C func */
    const char  *ml_doc;    /* The __doc__ attribute, or NULL */
};
typedef struct PyMethodDef PyMethodDef;
```

In Cython, this is how I would declare it:

```
ctypedef struct PyMethodDef:
        const char *ml_name
        PyCFunction ml_meth
        int ml_flags
        const char *ml_doc
```

From `PyCFunction`, I cannot seem to be able to change the `self` parameter of it and re-point the `ml_meth` struct slot to the newly wrapped `PyCFunction`.